# Wrong date from string with NSDateFormatter "HH:mm EE, MMM dd, YYYY"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I receive wrong date when I convert string to date with NSDateForamtter.

NSDateFormatter definition:

```
        dateFormatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm EE, MMM dd, YYYY"];
```

String that I want to convert:

```
2013-09-29 09:25:07.787 Alice [1012:a0b] dateStr = 09:25 Tue, Oct 01, 2013
```

Date that I receive:

```
2013-09-29 09:25:15.665 Alice [1012:a0b] [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateStr] = 2012-12-25 07:25:00 +0000
```

It should be "2013-10-01 09:25:00 +0000" instead of "2012-12-25 07:25:00 +0000". I am from Israel so I am in GMT + 2 , but why I receive December 2012 instead of October 2013?

Comment: there are TONS of date formatter question here on SO. Cant be that we start one for each format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct following line your code.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm EE, MMM dd, YYYY"];
```

with

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm EE, MMM dd, yyyy"];
```